# Tools and best practices for organizing large javascript applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I am developing fairly complex webapps/dashboards, mostly in Javascript. I like to use mongo and node on the server, but on the client there is usually an application-specific chaos of libraries and scripts.

My current project includes a combination of [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), [jquery](http://jquery.com/), [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/), [D3](http://d3js.org/), [leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/), [crossfilter](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/) and some obscure stuff, and it is fair to say that, although the application is awesome, the code has become an unholy mess. Especially code for D3 and crossfilter is quite verbose, see e.g. source of the official [crossfilter demo](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/) for a typical example.

So the question: *What are good tools and best practices of organizing large javascript applications?*

I already avoid global variables and try to organize namespaces with closures, but I am afraid I need some more structure than this. On the server there is npm which is quite nice, but is there something similar in the browser?

I have looked into [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) and [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/), but I am not quite sure if these will really solve the problem or only add complexity.

Comment: While an interesting question, have you looked into the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)? Which more or less states that this type of question is at least `Off Topic` or more likely `Not Constructive`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish perhaps link to where this -should- be posted?

Comment: @tybro0103 - On some other forum? Not here, SE Programmers probably not, what else is there on SO? SO is not all encompassing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're already on the right path, but here's a few tips:

1. Use a framework. [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) is popular right now, but there's others too. It will significantly help with code organization. In fact, a framework is an absolute must to avoid spaghetti code if your app is of any size at all. Other popular frameworks include [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) and [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).
2. If you decide not to use one of those frameworks, do at least use templating. Such as [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) or the one built in to underscore.
3. Combine and minify your files. Mostly to optimize load times. Ideally you'll find something to add to your backend that will do this for you. Rails' "Asset pipeline" for example uses something called [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets).
4. I do hear people raving about [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/). It doesn't really add functionality, but those who like it say it makes their code cleaner.

Comment: Each point, I see a means to argue. Hence, my comment vote. See the definition for `Not Constructive` for where that originates.

Comment: I agree...I was just wondering if there's a place where such a question does belong. People needs answers to these questions too.

Answer (score 2):

I think a 'modular' approach is what you need and the use of modules might help you get out of the chaos.

You can have a look at the following:

http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/

http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

http://www.2ality.com/2011/04/modules-and-namespaces-in-javascript.html